# Get errors when accessing admin panel

Tags: php, hosting, admin, backend

I am trying to set up the admin panel for a mobile app template (with cms) that I bough and after linking the database and trying to access the admin panel I get the following errors, and I really have no idea what to do. Thanks so much to anyone who can help me!

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 257

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cafeducap/admin/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 672

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cafeducap/admin/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 546

Comment: `headers already sent` is because functions that modify HTTP headers must be invoked before any output is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error,

in `system/core/common.php`file change

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

to

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

It will work fine.