# Only variable references should be returned by reference

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

As of today, when I'm accessing my website it comes up an error below:

A PHP Error was encountered

**Severity: Notice**

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 257

A PHP Error was encountered

**Severity: Warning**

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hbtlaw/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 675

A PHP Error was encountered

**Severity: Warning**

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hbtlaw/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 438

I have tried the solution on below link but it still doesn't work

> [Get errors when accessing admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997040/get-errors-when-accessing-admin-panel)
>
> [Only variable references should be returned by reference - Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter)

**By changing**

Edit filename: core/Common.php, line number: 257

**Before**

return $_config[0] =& $config;

**After**

$_config[0] =& $config; return $_config[0];

Please advice if someone ever experience the issue like I had.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...

This error pop when you try to send some header information to the browser but headers are already sent. In your case it's probably because of your variable issue. Don't try to fix the header error. What you need to do is, just create the correct flow of data and i will automatically fix. We can help you with that if you can show us the functions that course the issue.